# Cordova android app stop event

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio, cordova

I am developing a Cordova application using Visual Studio. On Android, I'd like to detect when the user close the app (using a long press on the device's menu button, and then a swipe). I m unable to do this using Cordova standard events (onPause/onResume).

onPause event fires when I tap on the device's home button. I tried both events `document.body.unload` and `window.unload`. They work well on Windows Phone, but can't get them working on Android.

I also tried to detect the event using a Cordova plugin (https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-ondestroy), but it seems to be outdated. In the JavaScript console, it states "class not found".

Any help ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the issue is still relevant today, so I've written a plugin that mostly fixes this. It listens for the `onWindowFocusChanged` native event on Android, which is fired when the activity loses or gains focus. This means it does fire when the menu button is pressed. It also has events for focus loss/gain on iOS, which covers opening the iOS app switcher.

https://github.com/distinctdan/cordova-plugin-extra-events

**However**, on Android I've found if the user is fast enough, they can still open the app switcher and kill the app before the event has a chance to run.

Answer (score -1):

I m trying to answer a part of your question. I too faced similar issue in my hybrid mobile app development related to invoking unload events. This is how i made unload events work in iOS and android,

**iOS**:

```
$(window).unload(function() { ... }
```

**Android**:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { ... }
```

Comment: @rubikonx9, dint understand why the response was rated -1

Comment: Neither do I. My *edit* concerned formatting of code samples. I didn't rate at all.

Comment: @rubikonx9, But it did show ur name, next to the rating :( Not sure whats wrong...